# "Compete with" or "compete against"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Is it correct to say *compete with* or *compete against*? I think *compete against* is the proper way, but *compete with* is extremely popular these days. Here's an example: It should be

> Apple MacOS **competes against** Windows 7...

but I have seen the other way.

Comment: Are you asking a question? Or is this just a language peeve? Peeves are off-topic, and it seems that many people use "compete with" as a synonym for "compete against".

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇, I edited the question to tone down the peeving. I think it's still a real question.

Comment: Would using the word `rivals` work? Usage: `Apple macOS rivals Windows 7.`

Answer (score 5):

The OED has 17 citations including ‘compete against’ and 130 including ‘compete with’.  The equivalent figures from the Corpus of Contemporary American English are 569 and 3335 and from the British National Corpus 85 and 552. That evidence clearly favours ‘compete with’, but I have no quarrel with either. ‘Warn’ is not alone in collocating both with ‘against’ and ‘with’. ‘Argue’ and ‘fight’ do so as well.

Comment: +1 for noting that *compete with* is more common than *compete against* in the corpora by a ratio of about 6 to 1. Both are clearly grammatical, and the original questioner's dispreferred variation is obviously the most idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

I think the tendency to use "with" - which I don't find at all problematic - comes from the fact that the prefix at the beginning of the word (*com-*) means "together."

The word itself [comes from](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=compete&searchmode=none) the Latin words for "strive" and "together."

I think competing *with* someone *for* something is perfectly good usage. The "with" implies that you share a goal, not that you're on the same team.

Comment: That is a nice way of putting it. I tend to use the combinations "Compete with" and " play against"

Answer (score 3):

The earliest meaning of "with" was "against", both in the sense of "next to" and in the sense of "in opposition to".  (Compare German "wider").

So "fight/strive with" are as old as "fight/strive against", and as @Barrie England says, "compete with" has always been more common than "compete against".

Answer (score 3):

I believe that either is correct, as others have stated, but I sense a slight difference in connotation between the two phrases.

Competing **against** someone or something indicates a targeted approach to competition where a competitor is focused specifically on one of its competition.  I sense a bit of aggression or animosity in the phrase.

Competing **with** someone or something, on the other hand,  seems to imply a less targeted, more individualist, less antagonistic form of competition.

Apple competes against Google.  I compete with others in the labor market.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but it might be interesting to the OP that what Andrew described is exactly how I feel about compete against / with.